# Common lisp: what is the return value of prog2?

Tags: common-lisp, return-value

One would expect `prog2` to differ from `prog1` and `progn` in returning the result of evaluating the *second* expression instead of the *first* and *last*, respectively.
However, the [HyperSpec](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/m_prog1c.htm) says something different (emphasis mine):

> [prog2](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/m_prog1c.htm#prog2) *[evaluates](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/26_glo_e.htm#evaluate)* *first-form*, then *second-form*, and then *forms*, *yielding* as its only *[value](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/26_glo_v.htm#value)* the *[primary value](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/26_glo_p.htm#primary_value)* *yielded* by ***first-form***.

That would mean that `prog2` would return the same (and, in fact, behave much) like `prog1`!

Interestingly, the examples in the HyperSpec confirm the *expected* rather than the *specified* behaviour:

> ```
> (setq temp 1) =>  1
> (prog2 (incf temp) (incf temp) (incf temp)) =>  3
> temp =>  4
> (prog2 1 (values 2 3 4) 5) =>  2
> ```

Is this a typo in the standard or am I missing something deeper?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This seems to be a [known issue](https://www.cliki.net/Issue%20PROG2-RETURN-VALUE) with the ANSI standard (the full list can be found on [CLiki](https://www.cliki.net/ANSI%20Clarifications%20and%20Errata)).

I have tested it with SBCL 2.0.1 as well as with a recent version of Allegro and in both cases it behaves as expected (rather than as specified):

```
CL-USER> (prog2
             (print "1st")
             (print "2nd")
           (print "3rd"))

"1st" 
"2nd" 
"3rd" 
"2nd"
```

Come to think of it, even the indentation seems to suggest so.

Comment: Feel free to edit or post your own answer if you know more about the topic. Even though it is a known issue, I haven't found anything about on SO, which is a pity.

Comment: This is the correct answer: `prog2` returns the primary value of the second form in its body.  `prog2` existed in Maclisp and its [description in the Pitmanual](https://www.maclisp.info/pitmanual/contro.html#5.16) is unambiguous.  This is just an edito in the ANSI standard.  It is interesting that `prog2` predated `prog1`!

Comment: my guess is `prog2` was needed as a poor man's `unwind-protect`, where you do `(prog2 (init-something) (compute) (cleanup-something))`, whereas `prog1` is more like a nice-to-have syntactic sugar

Answer (score 2):

For interest, I can enter the following code into Portacle (Emacs / SLIME / SBCL):

```
(prog2
   (print "1st")
   (print "2nd")
   (print "3rd"))
```

I placed the cursor on `prog2`, and used key sequence `M-.`. This shows what SBCL is actually doing.

```
(sb-xc:defmacro prog2 (form1 result &body body)
  `(prog1 (progn ,form1 ,result) ,@body))
```

So SBCL is pattern matching on the forms supplied. The first parameter is form `form1` and the second parameter is form `result`, anything else is called `body`. The function `progn` returns the value of form `result` whilst evaluating `form1`, and `prog1` picks this value also whilst evaluating `body`.

Conclusion - it's doing the sensible thing, not what the Hyperspec says.